# NodeJS render result of MySQL query properly

Tags: node.js, express

I got a **MySQL query** where I ask for the values in a specific field with the help of the `SELECT` statement. My question is: How do I get the value of the query ? When I render the template with my current code I receive following output on my page **[object Object]**. I have the following Code:

```
var network;

function query(sql, callback) {
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(rows);
            res.render('index.hjs', { Mysql : network });
            console.log(network);
        }
    });
}

query("SELECT testString FROM test", function(results){
    network = results;
});
```

Comment: you are asking the same question over and over again, just waiting for StackOverflow to solve all logic steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of corrections in your code. Nothing wrong but just good practice. In error callback, you are sending two arguments but in actual query callback function, you are using only one argument.

Second thing is that res will be undefined inside `query` function. (Of course, unless you have it inside request handler, which spoils the purpose of having it as a function)

Without your database structure and code structure, this is the best I can do to help you.